# I am trying to connect to abfss directly(without mounting to DBFS) and trying to open json file using open() in databricks

Tags: azure, pyspark, azure-blob-storage, azure-databricks, open-json

I am trying to connect to abfss directly(without mounting to DBFS) and trying to open json file using open() method in databricks.

json_file = open("abfss://@.dfs.core.windows.net/test.json') databricks is unable to open file present in azure blob container and getting below error :
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'abfss://@.dfs.core.windows.net/test.json'

I have done all the configuration setting using service principal. Please suggest other way of opening file using abfss direct path.

Answer (score 7):

the `open` method works only with local files - it doesn't know anything about `abfss` or other cloud storages.  You have following choice:

1. use `dbutils.fs.cp` to copy file from ADLS to local disk of driver node, and then work with it, like: `dbutils.fs.cp("abfss:/....", "file:/tmp/my-copy")`
2. Copy file from ADLS to driver node using the [Azure SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/data-lake-storage-directory-file-acl-python)

The first method is easier to use than second

Comment: Thanks @Alex Ott, I will try to implement this.

Comment: This is such a great solution that is far better than using sas token urls to access files.  I used this with openpyxl to extract sheets from xlsx files in synapes notebooks.  Before your solution, I kept getting 'file not found' errors. openpyxl needs the local file system. Copying from ADLS to local is perfect for my solution. Thank you.